# Storing subset of defined options into another table column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I am working on a rewrite for a registration app and starting to think about how I want to design the DB structure. I need the app to be flexible because some events offer different things. Here's a particular one:

Each event offers shirts, but not every event offers the same sizes. I figured I'd have a Shirt_Size table with all possible options and then in a form to create a new Event, they'd be able to just checkbox what shirts they want. Where would I store the particular subset of sizes for that particular event? I will need to query that to populate a drop down for the form that will be for registering for events.

I figured I could do some kind of comma-separated column for the Event model that is different value IDs from Shirt_Sizes?  But I've been reading that it's bad to do that, so I'm not sure how this is normally handled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third table that has a column for event_id and shirt_size_id and populate it as necessary.  Say event1 only has small and medium shirts, you would add two rows to the table.

```
id  event_id      shirt_size_id
1   1             1
2   1             2
```

And if the 2nd event had small medium and large shirts, add 3 rows to the new table.

```
id  event_id      shirt_size_id
3   2             1
4   2             2
5   2             3
```

Then when you query for data to populate the drop down, you can join all three tables.